# Send a styled Dataframe in the body of an email

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe

i have this function below which makes my dataframe pretty with a border and some highlighting. However, because I have used `.style` I cant use `.to_html()` to put the dataframe in the body an email so i use `.render()`. However, when I use `render()` the border formatting changes slightly. There is a picture below of what it looks like in Python which is how I want it, and another picture for how it looks in the email. Any idea how i can put the styled dataframe into a body of an email whilst keeping the formatting?

```
import win32com.client
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time
import os

curr_date = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
csv = pd.read_csv("Pipeline_Signals_" + curr_date + ".csv", delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
df = df1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

def _color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'red' if "*" in val else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df = (df.style
    .applymap(_color_red_or_green) 
    .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('border-color', 'black'),('background-color', 'white'), ('border-style','solid')]}])
    .hide_index() 
    .set_properties(**{'color': 'black',
                       'border-style' :'solid',
                       'border-color': 'black'}))

df1 = df.render()

import win32com.client

inbox = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

mail = inbox.CreateItem(0x0)
mail.To = "test@test.co.uk"
mail.CC = "test@test.co.uk"
mail.Subject = "Test Signals " + curr_date

mail.HTMLBody = df1

mail.Display()
```

This is what the dataframe looks like in Python and what I want it to look like

[image]

This is what the dataframe looks like when i put it in the body of an email. For some reason, the borders change.

[image]

Comment: If you could paste the html source of your table, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it comes from the CSS sheet used by default when your table is displayed. You should try to set the CSS "border-collapse" attribute of your table to "collapse" when you style it. If it doesn't work, try to set the "border-spacing" attribute to 0.